Dont show either scroll bar and auto resize frame using embed code
I'm currently using the embedded code below. How can this be amended so that the frame auto resizes based on content and both horizontal and vertical scrollbars are hidden?
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 70px; height: 20px; overflow:  
hidden;"><iframe style="width: 400px; height: 700px; margin-top: -100px; 
margin-left: -200px;" src="https://xxxxx.aspx" width="320" height="240"></iframe>
</div>

I'm expecting both scrollbars not to be visible.

Hi, your code isn't attached to your question.


